# data extraction from xls using xlrd in python

Tags: python, excel, list, xlrd

I am trying to extract the data from an *.xls file* and making a list but i am getting the list as `[u'elem1', u'elem2', u'elem3']`, but if i print separately i get as:

```
elem1
elem2
elem3
```

what is that u thing and how to remove it?

Here is my code...

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
xls=open_workbook('name.xls')
for sheets in xls.sheets():
    list1=[]
    for col in range(sheets.ncols):
        for rows in range(sheets.nrows):
            list1.append(sheets.cell(rows, col).value)
print(list1)
for i in list1:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the text as string,while appending data to the list in **list1.append(str(sheets.cell(rows, col).value))** to remove **[u'** .The code will be:

```
   from xlrd import open_workbook
   xls=open_workbook('name.xls')
   for sheets in xls.sheets():
       list1=[]
       for col in range(sheets.ncols):
           for rows in range(sheets.nrows):
               list1.append(str(sheets.cell(rows, col).value))
       print(list1)
       for i in list1:
           print i
```

Comment: Only do that if you are sure you will never find non ascii characters like `éôîïñ`...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Python 2.x, the `u` thing says that xlrd gives you unicode strings (what Excel strings really are). If you want to convert them in Python 2.7 strings, you have to encode them *with the charset you use*

Assuming you use latin1 (also knows as iso-8859-1 or (with minimal differences) windows-1252,
you can transform your list of unicode strings in a list of latin1 strings that way :

```py
strlist = [ elt.encode('latin1') for elt in list1 ]
```

or if you have only ASCII characters

```py
strlist = [ str(elt) for elt in list1 ]
```

Comment: Only one who actually explained to the user what the 'u' is.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by doing

```
str(variable_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

For practical matters, the `u` in the beginning won't affect u. U can work with them as well unless you have some issues related to encoding it in different formats.