# how to extract all the data in a single column in excel sheet using sikuli python

Tags: xlrd

This selecting a single data from excel sheet. Now i want to fetch all the data from the excel sheet. Can somebody help me to solve this problem

I have tried this code:

```
import xlrd
import datetime
EXCELFILE = "D:\\Muthu\\Datamanipulation\\book1.xlsx"
book = xlrd.open_workbook(EXCELFILE)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
celltype = sheet.cell_type(40,33)
value = sheet.cell_value(40,33)
```

Comment: I want to fetch all data in an particular column in an excel sheet

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26672349/1119381. Nothing to do with Sikuli.

Comment: Thanks Eugene.It Solved My problem